# How to split string after the last digit

Tags: python, pandas, split

To clean a dataset, I need to split a string after the last digit. Any idea ?

**My dataframe:**

```
data = {'addr':[
         "510 -1, Cleveland St", 
         "RC-20-5345 Poplar Street", 
         "3600 Race Avenue Richardson"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   addr
_____________________________________
   510 -1, Cleveland St
   RC-20-5345 Poplar Street
   3600 Race Avenue Richardson
```

I tried with this expression, but I missed floor number (RC) in the second row.

```
df["split1"] = df["addr"].str.extract(r"(\d+[-\ ]+\d*)")

  split1   | split2
___________|_________________________
510 -1     |  , Cleveland St
20-5345    |  Poplar Street
3600       |  Race Avenue Richardson
```

**What I m looking for:**

```
  split1   | split2
___________|_________________________
510 -1     |  , Cleveland St
RC-20-5345 |  Poplar Street
3600       |  Race Avenue Richardson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def splitByLastDigit(x):
    lastDigit=0
    splitOne=""
    splitTwo=""
    finalArray=[]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        if x[i].isdigit() and i > lastDigit:
            lastDigit=i

    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        if i <= lastDigit:
            splitOne+=x[i]
        else:
            splitTwo+=x[i]
    if len(splitTwo.strip()) == 1 and splitTwo.strip().isalpha():
        return [splitOne+splitTwo]
    finalArray.append(splitOne)
    finalArray.append(splitTwo)
    return finalArray
```

Just wrote up this solution. It is a bit rough (*can definitely be done more elegant*) but tested it with the three examples you provided and gets the job done.

Pretty simple idea. Collects the index of the last digit, then another loop checks which characters are before and after that index. Lastly, appends to it an array and returns the final results.

Comment: Your function covers about 80% of the cases, except the case where the civic number is 1899A and 1885 B, do you have an idea how to cover these cases?

Comment: @AdilBlanco
I tested my function with both cases and it seemed to work fine. 
I got -> ['1899', 'A'] for 1899A and -> ['1885', ' B'] for 1885 B

If you want to split at the last digit, this is exactly what is happening for both cases. Please elaborate what is exactly wrong.

Comment: exactly I don't want to split it in this case, I noticed that the civic numbers are badly formed, what I m looking for in this case is 1899A -> ['1899A'] and 1885 B-> ['1885 B']

Comment: Oh so the exception is if the last character is non-digit then maintain it as the same element?

Comment: @HARRIBI Exactly, sometimes the same building has two civic numbers.

Comment: but for the 1885 B case, there are two characters after the last non-digit, and you still want to maintain both?

Comment: No problem, the importance that they go together ['1885 B'] or ['1885B']

Comment: @AdilBlanco
Hey there, sorry for the late response. I just edited the code to account for a trailing single character. Simply checked if there is one more character and if that character is a letter. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

what about just adding a wildcard match to the front of the regex?

```py
df["split1"] = df["addr"].str.extract(r"(.*\d+[-\ ]+\d*)")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and how to do for the rest of the string (split2) ?

Comment: does something like df["split1"], def["split2"] = df["addr"].str.extract(r"(.*\d+[-\ ]+\d*)(.*)", expand=True) work?

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on zyd's answer, capture the remainder in another group

```py
data = {'addr':[
         "510 -1, Cleveland St", 
         "RC-20-5345 Poplar Street", 
         "3600 Race Avenue Richardson"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['split1','split2']] = df["addr"].str.extract(r"(.*\d+[-\ ]+\d*)(.+)")
```

```
                          addr       split1                  split2
0         510 -1, Cleveland St       510 -1          , Cleveland St
1     RC-20-5345 Poplar Street  RC-20-5345            Poplar Street
2  3600 Race Avenue Richardson        3600   Race Avenue Richardson
```